# How does this non-isolated buck converter work?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, buck, mains, converter

I found this converter-circuit on the Internet. I will use it to power an IR2153, which contains a 15,6V zener.
I chose to use it because of the large losses of a resistive dropper.
The unmarked voltages are unknown.
Diodes- high speed (BA159, UF4007 etc.)

[image: Circuit]

Comment: very dangerously

Answer (score 2):

Very inefficiently: The 0.22uF cap and 100 ohm resistor create an RC oscillator, periodically turning on BUX85. The 4.7mH inductor smoothes out the voltage somewhat, and the zener tries to make it a regulated 15ish volts. Altogether it's an inefficient and dangerous design. Good luck getting it to pass UL.

Comment: This isn't a production design.. also, it's on the mains side anyway. For me, _as long as it doesn't go_ **BANG** _it's ok!_

Comment: Besides, max. output current is ~20mA.

Comment: to me I see  resonance of 4.7mH and 100uF near 250Hz and 100 ohm as a current limiter for 0.7V/100 for 7mA, not an oscillator besides UL does not care if it is used outside US with 50Hz, 230V